# Переменные-счётчики.

Tags: code-style

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие бывают стандартные имена для переменных-счётчиков? кроме i,j?

UPD: вот уж не думал, что этот простой вопрос перерастёт в такую дискуссию.. всем спасибо, мыло интересно узнать ваше мнение)

Comment: каждый может вбить какой ему вздумается. i,j,k - самые распространенные

Comment: Ага, спасибо... А то в олимпиадной задаче уже шесть вложенных циклов for..

Comment: @Dazar, 6 вложенных циклов, это явно перебор!

Скорее всего надо пересмотреть алгоритм, в крайнем случае поместить 2-3 внутренних цикла в функцию.

Comment: @avp, Если хотите, могу поделиться заданием, мне не жалко)
А в функцию уже пихаю, без неё никак(

Comment: @Dazar, 6 вложенных циклов точно перебор, и я почти уверен, что олимпиадная задачка подразумевала другое решение, и наверняка такое решение (O(n^6)), скорее всего не пройдёт по скорости.

Comment: @delphist007, вы правы. Действительно, то решение не влезло в ограничение по времени(2 секунды). Пришлось думать над другим, которое оказалось в десять раз проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если много вложенных, можно например именовать: `i1, i2, i3`, ...

Счетчики разные можно сделать:

1. просто перечисления в массивах **i**, **j**
2. перебор по координатам **x**, **y**, **z**
3. перебор по времени **t** (`time`), **y** (`year`), **m** (`month`), **d** (`day`) ...

мне было бы интересно задачку почитать )

Answer (score 0):

Задача точно не поместится в комментарий, оформляю её отдельным ответом.  
Прошу обратить **внимание**, что **я нашёл** более **простой** и **оптимальный** путь её решения, без шести циклов. Потом могу рассказать решение, если попросите.

Одной из важных задач, возникающих при разработке почтового клиента, является реализация подстановки адреса в процессе набора. Необходимо по нескольким введенным пользователем буквам находить в адресной книге все адреса, которые он может иметь в виду. Рассмотрим подробнее, как это происходит. Если пользователь ввел строку S, то он может иметь в виду любой адрес, в котором S содержится как подстрока. Более того, если это условие не выполняется, но будет выполняться, если в S заменить (именно заменить, а не удалить или вставить) один или два символа на любые другие, то адрес также подходит (так как пользователь может помнить адрес неточно или опечататься). Соответственно, перед программистами встает следующая задача: выделить из адресной книги все адреса, в которые введенная пользователем строка S входит как подстрока с не более, чем двумя несовпадающими символами.

### Формат входного файла

В первой строке входного файла input.txt находится одно целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 30) - количество адресов в адресной книге. В следующих n строках содержатся сами адреса. Каждый адрес является строкой из не более, чем 100 символов, в которую входят только строчные буквы английского алфавита, ровно один символ "@"(at, собака) и ровно один символ "."(точка), причем гарантируется, что точка в каждом адресе идет после собаки и отделена от нее хотя бы одним символом. Также гарантируется, что в каждом адресе после точки присутствует хотя бы один символ. Все адреса в книге различны. В следующей и последней строке входного файла содержится строка из не более, чем 100 строчных букв английского алфавита — то, что ввел пользователь.

### Формат выходного файла

В первой строке файла output.txt выведите одно целое число — количество адресов, подходящих под описанное условие. Далее выведите все подходящие адреса в том же порядке, в каком они даны во входном файле. Каждая строка выходного файла должна содержать ровно один адрес. Каждый подходящий адрес должен встречаться ровно один раз. Не выводите лишних символов (пробелов, табуляций).

### Пример входных и выходных данных

*input.txt*
5
petrpetrov@email.com
ivanivanov@email.ru
vetrovalexey@email.ua
olegpestov@post.ru
petyaivanov@post.ua
petrov

*output.txt*
3
petrpetrov@email.com
vetrovalexey@email.ua
olegpestov@post.ru

Comment: да, интересная задачка )
на codeforces.ru/ не пробовал участвовать? )

Comment: прочитал вопрос.  
> какие бывают стандартные имена для переменных-счётчиков? кроме i,j?  

прочитал начало задачи.  
> Одной из важных задач, возникающих при разработке почтового клиента, является реализация подстановки адреса в процессе набора.  
 
снова прочитал вопрос.  
дальше начал читать задачу.   

вошел когнитивный диссонанс.  

----  

Не поймите меня неправильно, но человек не понимающий таких элементарных истин, пишет логику для почтового клиента (и Б-г знает, что еще)? Ни на что не намекаю, никого не ущемляю, но неужели мне одному это все показалось странным?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, господи, я же писал, что это задача из тренировки к олимпиаде для школьников. И тем более, какая разница, даже если мне и сорок лет, я бородатый-волосатый, и тут мне захотелось узнать, как другие "программисты" называют переменные. Что тут такого?

Comment: Если это - интересная задачка, то я - Исус Христос. Всю жизнь занимаюсь такими скучными вещами

Comment: Уважаемый @Dazar,  
1. "Ни на что не намекаю, никого не ущемляю"  
2. вы написали "в олимпиадной задаче". Фразы "для школьников" не было.  
3. Нет никаких "писаных правил" обзывания переменных. 95% людей обзывают переменные так, как хотят. Остальные 5% делают это так, чтобы было понятно им и всем остальным, кто может когда-нибудь глянуть на код. Разумеется, если у вас простой цикл, или если в нем только один вложенный цикл, то нет надобности в расписывании переменных. А если, как у вас, то нужно называть их в соответствие с тем, что они означают. Чтобы на 100 вложении было понятно, что это.

Comment: Разумеется, если у вас простой цикл, или если в нем только один вложенный цикл, то нет надобности в расписывании переменных. А если, как у вас, то нужно называть их в соответствие с тем, что они означают. Чтобы на 100 вложении было понятно, что это.

Answer (score -3):

Лично я бы поубивал тех, кто использует непонятные имена переменных в своих программах. Хуже, чем объявлять переменные одной буквой - быть не может. Имя каждой переменной должно отражать суть своего содержания. Конечно, это не касается, например, координатной системы, где X и Y это общепринятые обозначения в математике, ну и подобных случаев.

Одним словом, не юзайте i,j, а пишите сразу что-то внятное, чтобы другой человек, который возможно будет инспектировать код, мог сразу понять суть того, что вы делаете в коде.

На почве такого вопроса, я не могу не посоветовать книги:

- [С. Макконел "Совершенный код"](http://piter.com/book.phtml?978546900822);
- [Р. Мартин "Чистый код"](http://piter.com/book.phtml?978544610069).

Comment: Что-то вы слегка перегнули. Только полный чайник может не понять когда, например, в цикле for используется переменная $i в качестве переменной счетчика. Если вы со мной не согласны, то думаю, что для начала, вам надо написать выговор [этим ребятам](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php), мол пусть нубы учаться "чистому и совершеннрму коду"

Comment: @Drac5, IMHO `i,j,k` при переборе всех элементов массива это такая же *идиома*, как и `x,y,z` для декартовых координат.

Если же значение переменной цикла будет использовано после него (скажем, в поиске максимума), то конечно, лучше ее именовать более понятно. Например, `imax_salary`  - индекс максимума в массиве зарплат (на мой вкус imxsal тоже сгодиться).

А вот `maximum_salary_index` - это уже чересчур громоздко и будет скорее мешать восприятию кода.

Comment: @avp Вы категорически не правы. external_loop_counter и inner_loop_counter намного понятней, чем `i` и `j`. И килобайтов исходного текста больше, т.е. если платят за вес...

Comment: @alexlz, больше вес? Убедительный аргумент, а особенно для индусов )) На их аналогичном форуме, вы бы сразу лидирующее положение заняли. "*Чем больше кода - тем больше риса на обед*"

Comment: @avp, Мне кажется, что отчасти Drac5 прав. Если цикл не содержит вложенных циклов, то `i` ещё нормально смотрится, но вот когда есть вложенные... Иной раз происходит большая путаница. Поэтому во многих случаях, всё таки стоит отказаться от "стандартных" имён счётчика циклов, в пользу более значащих. Но так категорично, как сказал @Drac5, я бы не стал выражаться.

Comment: @Drac5, В моём коде переменная бы называлась current_first_char_position_for_replacement. Вы считаете, что это лучше, чем j?

Comment: >> Хуже, чем объявлять переменные одной буквой - быть не может

Дело не в количестве букв, а в читабельности кода. Если вы делаете перебор массива, то там нафиг не нужен **index** вместо **i**.

Comment: Есть такая вещь - математическая традиция. В системе математических обозначений индексирование традиционно обозначается буквами по порядку применения i, j и т.д.

Comment: Омфг, какие дискуссии за один день.
Да, если смотреть на простейшие циклы с одним/двумя уровнями вложенности, то конечно это не нужно. Особенно, если это в обучающий материалах.
Но извините, если я пишу в основном ООП, то имена объектов мне хочется обозначать так, чтобы это было читабельно. Не факт, что я буду этот код поддерживать через год и хочу минимум вопросов иметь от другого программиста.
Длинные имена, как "current_first_char_position_for_replacement", это перебор. 
Ну и как было уже сказано, 6 вложенных циклов - это просто пушистый зверек какой-то. Код должен быть отрефакторен.

Comment: `i`, `j` и `k` - исторически принятые переменные, ноги которых растут с фортрана (там тип переменных определялся по первой букве), где эти переменные были целого типа. И для небольших циклов это самые правильные переменные (если только там явно не нужно писать x\y или подобное).

Прикрывать все умными книгами - плохо. Открываем того же С. Макконел "Совершенный код", пункт 11.2 и видим
>> как правило в качестве переменных цикла используются i, j k

В главе 16 он уже говорит другое, но тройной вложенный цикл это подозрительно.

Но в олимпиадных задачах, можно писать тройные циклы, хоть с a b c.

Comment: Разбирая код, в котором содержатся циклы, я скорее буду искать переменные с названием i, j, k, вместо current_first_char, inner_loop_counter и других, которые только осложнят анализ. Вдруг вам в голову придет назвать переменные вроде: 

> number_fiend, number_friend 

Фу, фу, фу. Гораздо понятней оставить комментарий в начале цикла и использовать обычные i, j, k.

Comment: @lampa, предположим есть цикл с сотней вложенных циклов (бред полный, но допустим :), вас уже на 10 вложенности начнет бесить подниматься вверх по портянке, чтобы посмотреть комментарий и понять, что означает очередная "i25"...

Comment: @teanЫЧ это скорее исключение, чем правило :)

Comment: если появилась необходимость делать десять вложенных циклов, то это скорее всего значит, что у программиста что то не то в консерватории. В таких случаях (если возникает необходимость), нужно внутренние циклы выносить в отдельные функции. и не будет никаких `i100500`.